# simscript executable file is missing

Tags: simulation, simscript

I am trying to get my feet wet in SimScript simulation.

I wrote a simple code contains a function that returns the its first parameter.

This is my code:

```
preamble
        define Normal.fn as a double function
end
function Normal.fn (means, f)
        define means, f as double variables
        return (means)
end
main
        let x = Normal.fn(2.1,3.1)
end
```

However, when I execute the project, I got an error message states:

```
The executable file MyProject.exe is missing
```

I build and rebuild the project many times, but I am still having this problem.

I noticed in my `executable` folder, the MyProject.exe has not been generated.

I don't know what is going on, I am new to this programming language.

Could you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself,

It was a missing library in the simscript version 3, i check the simscript version 2 libraries through file system and I found it, it is the one named "IDebugC.c"